# How to draw line continuously from placed anchor to screen center using ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I am exploring arkit. I want to draw a line using two anchors same as [ArRuler](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ar-ruler-app-tape-measure/id1326773975). Here is the scenario.

1. User taps on screen
2. An anchor1 should be placed on the position of screen center.
3. Line should be drawn continuously from the anchor1 to the screen center.
4. On the second tap, another "anchor2" should be placed. (Now two anchors are connected with the line)

I have placed first two anchors and after that I'm trying to draw line between them.
But that is not what I wanted. (I want continuous draw progress)

Here is what I did for adding an Anchor and drawing an object (SCNSphere in my case)

```
func addMarker(color: UIColor) {
        let geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.01)
        geometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = color

        let markerNode = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
        markerNode.position = ballNode.worldPosition

        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(markerNode)

    }
```

Here is what I did for drawing a line between two anchors.

```
 func addLineBetween(start: SCNVector3, end: SCNVector3) {
        let lineGeometry = SCNGeometry.lineFrom(vector: start, toVector: end)
        let lineNode = SCNNode(geometry: lineGeometry)
        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lineNode)
    }
```

Line is being drawn after placing second anchor :(